# Xamarin.Auth: Account.Create() is not secure

Tags: authentication, xamarin.auth

I am using Xamarin.Auth.XamarinForms to save the username and password so user no need to worry about remembering the password.

I received an error:

```
   This version is insecure, because of default password.
Please use version with supplied password for AccountStore:
    AccountStore.Create(Contex, string);
or
    AccountStore.Create(string);

Using:
    AccountStore.Create(Contex);
or
    AccountStore.Create();
```

In the library, only have the Create() and I did use that method. Do I need to worry about the message.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended action right now is to use `SecureStorage` instead.

Here's how to do the migration:
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/wiki/Migrating-from-AccountStore-to-Xamarin.Essentials-SecureStorage